# pyinstaller with pydantic v2 - `pydantic:compiled` has been removed in V2.`

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pydantic

i have a python app which i build with pyinstaller, and which i recently brought pydantic v2 into.

pydantic v1 was never used, or as far as i am aware installed on my system.

pyinstaller now fails to build with this error:

```
23401 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pydantic.py' from 'C:\\paul\\AmDesp\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...

pydantic.errors.PydanticImportError: `pydantic:compiled` has been removed in V2.
```

my app works fine if i run as a python script but i am unable to build it out to make portable...

i'm a novice but as far as i can tell this is an issue with pyinstaller not being pydantic v2 ready? rather than my code relying on v1 features or being otherwise wrong?

i waited to start learning pydantic because v2 was imminent by the time i was ready to roll, and i dont really want to have to roll it back and learn v1.

can someone confirm if pyinstaller is pydantic v2 ready? and if not give some advice about how i might overcome this? if i can contribute to making it ready i am happy to get involved but will need pointing at the actual problem-space and a brief intro... otherwise i guess i'm looking at other build-platforms?

Comment: I googled for "pydantic:compiler pyinstaller". See https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller-hooks-contrib/pull/611. Try `pip install -U pyinstaller-hooks-contrib`.

Comment: thanks, that worked.... but, errr, how come i - still! - can't find that link myself?!

Answer (score 3):

as provided by AKX (who apparently can use google better than i):

http://www.github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller-hooks-contrib/pull/611

`pip install -U pyinstaller-hooks-contrib`